# Check if nodes share a mutual connection in DiGraph

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am working with network data, trying to use a pandas dataframe to describe a networkx DiGraph. I would like rows for every pair in the graph and a column that indicates if there is both an edge `(node1,node2)` and `(node2,node1)`--that there is a mutual connection in the graph.

I can implement the following for a small graph, but it is too slow to be useful for a large graph.

```
edges = pd.DataFrame({'source': [0, 2, 2,5],
                  'target': [2, 0, 3,0])
UnD_Test = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges)
Test = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, create_using=nx.DiGraph())

link_df = pd.DataFrame(list(UnD_Test.edges))
link_df['Mutual'] = False

for val in range(len(link_df['Mutual'])):
    p1 = link_df.iloc[val][0]
    p2 = link_df.iloc[val][1]
    if ((p1,p2) in Test.edges()) & ((p2,p1) in Test.edges()):
         link_df['Mutual'][val] = True
```

What can I use to accomplish this faster?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pandas and Nnumpy for such tasks:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(list(Test.edges()), columns=['a','b'])

res = pd.DataFrame(
        np.unique(np.sort(x.merge(x.rename(columns={'a':'b', 'b':'a'})),
                          axis=1),
                  axis=0),
        columns=['a','b'])
```

result:

```
In [73]: res
Out[73]:
   a  b
0  0  2
```